# Unable to to do chaos Experiment on Azure SQL data base

Tags: azure-sql-database, gremlin, chaos, litmus, spring-boot-chaos-monkey

I'm new to Chaos engineering. I'm trying to attach PAAS service hosted in Azure like SSMS(Azure SQL).

I'm using LitmusChaos and Gremlin tools to connect and attack but fail. is there any way I can validate?
My objective to validate the Scaling-resilience and DR for SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

Chaos Experiment can only be performed on some targets which may directly or indirectly connected with Azure SQL Database, like **Network Security Group** (NSG).
I have tried to repro the same for NSG connected with Azure SQL Database and it is working fine for me.

Please follow the below steps:

1. Search for `Chaos Studio` in Azure Portal and select the same from the results.

[image]

2. Before that, create a NSG and add it to the SQL Server, under Networking, add the virtual network rule associated with the NSG for secure connection.

[image]

3. Now, in Chaos Studio, click on the Targets on left panel. Search for the NSG group you have created and select it. On the top `Enable targets` select Enable service-direct targets.

[image]

4. Next, create the Experiment on the same page. Give basic details, Experiment designer details with Fault details and Target resources details. Refer below images.

[image]

[image]

5. Once deployed, Start the experiment for the same.

[image]

6. Wait for the experiment to complete and check the status for the same.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. if you Ok  can I connect with you?

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the reply.

I tried in chaos studio but in step 3 in Chaos Studio, the "Enable Targets" is disabled when I clicked on targets.

steps performed:
a) created Azure SQL 
b) created network and link to SQL server.
c) Register Chaos studio in subscription.
d) navigate to chaos studio.



 the Targets on left panel. Search for the NSG group you have created and select it. On the top Enable targets select Enable service-direct targets.

Comment: it might be disabled because the targeted resource isn't in the list. Please check if resource there.